# Looking for a bound on a function involving $\sinh$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, hyperbolic-functions

Fix $T > 0$ and let $t \in (0,T)$ let $c > 1$ be a constant (which may be bigger than $T$).

Consider the function $$f(c,t,T) = \frac{\sinh ((T-t)c)}{\sinh (Tc)}.$$
I am looking for a bound of the form
$$f(c,t,T) \leq {K(t,T)}{c^{-\frac 12}} \qquad \text{for $t \in (0,T)$}$$
where $K(t,T)$ is a constant that depends on $t$ and $T$ (preferably in a continuous or a nice way). Can such a bound be possible?

By using half-angle formula, we can write 
$$f(c,t,T)=\cosh(tc)-\coth(Tc)\sinh(tc)$$
but I just don't see how to estimate it.

Comment: Having played around with the function's Taylor expansion I think I can say that $\text{sech}(ct)$ is an upper bound... not proved it though... not sure if this helps with your question any either !

Comment: @pbs juding by Wolframalpha for lots of values for $t$ and $T$ it's true but no idea how to prove it

Comment: I think that there is no such bound. Taylor expansion for numerator is
$$1 - ct\coth{(cT)} + \frac{c^2t^2}{2} + \ldots$$
Since series change signs, you have
$$f(c,t,T)\le 1 - ct\coth{(cT)} + \frac{c^2t^2}{2},$$
and for example $f(c,t,T)\le1 + c^2T^2/2$.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Sorry how did you get that Taylor expansion for the numerator?

Comment: @Upin, sorry, it's expansion for all $f(c,t,T)$.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Thanks. Maybe we should not neglect the negative term then.. I think it is true based on what I have graphed :|

Comment: @Upin, may be, but $f(c,t,T)< 1$ for $t\in(0,T)$, and I don't think that it's possible to find such bounds.

Comment: @Upin, could you show what you graphed?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Hmm, I think I was mistaken when I drew the graphs. Sorry about that. I thought of $c$ as a variable which is not right.,